# regular expressions matches characters on different lines at the start

Tags: boost, boost-regex

My question is how to match the first three characters of certain lines within a string using regular expressions the regex i have should work however when i run the program it only matches the first three characters of the first line the string is

`.V/RTEE/EW\n.N/ERER/JAN/21`

my regex is `^(.[VN]/)*` so it needs to match `.V/ and .N/` any help I will be very grateful

Answer (score 1):

You need to suppress the special meaning of the . and /
Use \ in-front of them.

Comment: Try this instead ^(\.[VN]\/)(.*)

Comment: hmm i thin the '.' whill catch the whole line though won't it ?

Comment: . will match any single character except space and * will catch 0 or any number of characters. If you still think only (.*) matches everything you can use $ which matches end of the string

Comment: ok i will try it when i log back onto the PC so this regeular expression should catch .V/ and .N/ or any three characters at the start of the line i.e .S/ if .S/EE/ER/GEE was there too and the regular expression had [VS] instead of [VN] ? (just to clarify)

Comment: if you want to catch any of three use [VSN]

Comment: this expression does not work it catch the whole line instead of .V/ .N/ .S/

Comment: Which RE are you using, it is working perfectly for me. It is ^(\.[VNS]\/)(.*)$